# PHP: How to push multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am reading a csv file from which I will create an associative array with the following layout:

```
  $arrProducts = array('111' => array('description' => 'product1',
                                     'inventory' => '222',
                                     'price' =>'9.2')),
                    '184'=> array('description' => 'product2',
                                     'inventory' => '52',
                                     'price'=>'1.19'));
```

So, if I have the following product information:

```
'199 '=> array('description' => 'product3',
                                     'inventory' => '52',
                                     'price'=>'1.19')
```

How do I add that to $arrProducts?

obs.: I need the associative array in this layout so I can access product information this way:

```
 echo $arrProducts['111']['description'];
```

Edit:

I tried using the code in the answer of the question marked as duplicated, so my code is like this:

```
$arrProducts = array('111' => array('description' => 'product1',
                                    'inventory' => '222',
                                    'price' =>'9.2'),
                     '184' => array('description' => 'product2',
                                    'inventory' => '52',
                                    'price'=>'1.19'));

$arrProducts[] = array('199'=> array('description' => 'product3',
                                 'inventory' => '52',
                                 'price'=>'1.19'));
```

But it is still not woorking as expected. I ran the following tests:

```
echo $arrProducts['111']['description'];
     //result: product1

echo $arrProducts['184']['description'];
     //result: product2

echo $arrProducts['199']['description'];
     //result: Notice: Undefined offset: 199 in C:\xampp\htdocs\arrTest.php on line 15
```

So I looped in every key of the array:

```
 foreach ($arrProducts as $key1 => $value1) {
            echo "[".$key1."]";}
  //result: [111][184][185]
```

So it seems that the key 185 is created automatically and inside it is the information. So I can access it like this:

```
 // echo $arrProducts['185']['199']['description'];
 //result: product3
```

But that that is not what I expect, I need to add the element and be able to access it in the same way it is possible for elements "111" and "184".

I expect something like this:

```
echo $arrProducts['199']['description'];
     //result:product3
```

Comment: Note `1,19` in one format, `1.19` in another. Inconsistencies like that can be a huge problem.

Comment: What does the CSV look like? Can't answer without knowing that.

Comment: Idk, but may be `$arrProducts =  array_replace($arrProducts, $anotherProductInformation);` can helps... :-/ This is for case with identical array structure.

Comment: Doesn't agree with duplicated mark with that answer. It doesn't cover request objectives. May be it duplicated, but this is wrong answer. Here is an associated array used.

Comment: @Wizard as far as the question is presented now, I think the linked duplicate is enough.

Comment: I edited the question to show why the answer in the question marked as duplicated does not work for me.