# Best way to modify an multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

There are many ways to modify an array but which is the best way to modify the following multidimensional array?

This array contain two other arrays, category 1 and 2.

```
$arr = array(
        'category 1' => array(
                        'item 1' => 'lorem',
                        'item 2' => 'lorem',
                        'item 3' => 'lorem',
                        'item 4' => 'lorem',
                        ),

        'category 2' => array(
                        'item 1' => 'lorem',
                        'item 2' => 'lorem',
                        'item 3' => 'lorem',
                        'item 4' => 'lorem',
                        ),
);
```

If I var_dump the array it will look like this.

```
array(2) {
  ["category 1"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["item 1"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 2"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 3"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 4"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
  }
  ["category 2"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["item 1"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 2"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 3"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 4"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
  }
}
```

So, what is the best way to add [category 3] and [subcategory 1], so it looks like below.

```
array(2) {
  ["category 1"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["item 1"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 2"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 3"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 4"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
  }
  ["category 2"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["item 1"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 2"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 3"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 4"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
        ["subcategory 1"]=>
        array(2) {
        ["item 1"]=>
        string(5) "lorem"
        ["item 2"]=>
        string(5) "lorem"
  }
  ["category 3"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["item 1"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 2"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 3"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"
    ["item 4"]=>
    string(5) "lorem"

  }
}
```

Comment: This is basic PHP arrays, what bit are you having a problem with? Please show the code you've tried.

Comment: It's strange, but I've just don't understand why it's not marked as duplicated. Similar with [this quiestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925910/php-how-to-push-multidimensional-associative-array#comment78811294_45925910). Here is no the best way to modify an array. It's depends from the code, your way, your mind, your experience.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the monodimensional arrays you need to add and simply add them to the first array:

```
$array['category_2']['subcategory_1'] = $subcategory_1_array;
$array['category_3'] = $category_3_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is one catch-all "best" way but for your specific case, this would suffice:

```
$arr = array(
    'category 1' => array(
                    'item 1' => 'lorem',
                    'item 2' => 'lorem',
                    'item 3' => 'lorem',
                    'item 4' => 'lorem',
                    ),

    'category 2' => array(
                    'item 1' => 'lorem',
                    'item 2' => 'lorem',
                    'item 3' => 'lorem',
                    'item 4' => 'lorem',
                    ),
);
$arr['category 3'] = array();

for($i = 1; $i < 5; ++$i){
    $arr['category 3']["item $i"] = 'lorem';
}
```